# Passing a data list value in asp.net ( closed )

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datalist

I have a datalist that bound to a database where now the label is change to a link button

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
.....some other datalist item 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

For this case I wanted the link button to fired up a new page where the Eval("username") value is passed to the new page.

I'm thinking about passing it using session such as ....

```
string any_variable ;
session["Picked_username_from_datalist"] = any_variable ;
response.redirect("newpage.aspx");
```

so that the variable that I'm going to pass using session can be manipulated.

But my problem is I have no idea how to assign the Text='<%# Eval("username") %> to the variable any_variable .....

~~ the assigned value for the variable is depends on the text of the databind that binded to the database .... for example ... 1st linkbutton text is username1 , and the 2nd is username2 and so on based on my SQL select command .....

I need the selected Text='<%# Eval("username") %> so that I can manipulate the information to display another databind control based on the value.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" event of DataList

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" >
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>' CommandName="Redirect">
        </asp:LinkButton>
        .....some other datalist item 
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

server side code is

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
    {
         Session["Picked_username_from_datalist"] = e.CommandArgument;
         Response.Redirect("newpage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naresh .... this idea seem to work .... thanks .... really nice sharing and discussing with u guys .....

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use item bound event

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   // here you can find the value as
       LinkButton lk= (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
    session["Picked_username_from_datalist"] = lk.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Waqar .... im still lost ... the value now is assigned to 1k is it ? ..... and what data type is now the value consists of ? .... thanks in advance ..

Comment: Thanks Waqar ...it seem work .... nice sharing and discussing with u guys .... pray all the good things for u and others ..... tq again ...

Comment: @toneinacone you are welcome. lk gets the reference of linkbutton present in the your datalist. and remember to mark as your answer the one who helps you the most.

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' CommandName="Assign" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>'>
     </asp:LinkButton>
    .....some other datalist item 
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
```

Notice the new properties `CommandName` and Command Argument added. Now you can use `ItemCommand` to do whatever you want.

```
void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
      {
         if(e.CommandName == "Assign") {
             string userName = e.CommandArgument;
         }

      }
```

Another simple way is to use hyperlink in place of link button.

```
<asp:hyperlink id="link1" href='<%#Eval("username","/yourpage.aspx?userName={0}")' />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Prashant .... thanks for the idea ... but the string doest seem to work with the e object .... but if we assign directly to the session it seem to work .... something like ....  Session["Picked_username_from_datalist"] = e.CommandArgument;